# How to Convert Arabic Characters to Unicode Using PHP

Tags: php, html, unicode, ar-php

I want to to know how can I convert a word into unicode exactly like:
http://www.arabunic.free.fr/

can anyone know how to do that using PHP considering that Arabic text may contains ligatures?

thanks

**Edit**

I'm not sure what is that "unicode" but I need to have the Arabic Character in it's equivalent machine number considering that arabic characters have different  contextual forms depending on their position - see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Table_of_basic_letters

the same character in different position:

> ب‎ | ـب‎ |    ـبـ‎ | بـ‎

I think it must be a way to convert each Arabic character into it's equivalent number, but how?

**Edit**

I still believe there's a way to convert each character to it's form depending on positions

any idea is appreciated..

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Unicode". "Unicode" is a character set with very little practical use. Do you mean a character **encoding** like UTF-8 or UTF-16? And **from** what do you want to convert? What the applet on the page you provided creates isn't really "Unicode" either, but JavaScript Unicode escape sequences, which you don't need either if you use UTF-8 or -16.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All what you need is function called: utf8Glyphs which you can find it in ArGlyphs.class.php download it from [ar-php](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ar-php/files/)
and visit [Ar-PHP](http://www.ar-php.org) for the ArPHP more information about the project and classes.

This will reverse the word with same of its characters (glyphs).

**Example of usage:**

```
    <?php
    include('Arabic.php');
    $Arabic = new Arabic('ArGlyphs');

    $text = 'بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم';
    $text = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs($text);
    echo $text;
    ?>
```

Comment: this is interesting. yet I got each equivalent right from arabic to utf-8 .. just I need the way where I can change encoding to windows-1256 and all is done :) thx

Comment: Output would be useful

Answer (score 3):

i assume you wnat to convert بهروز to \u0628\u0647\u0631\u0648\u0632 take a look at http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/ all you have to do after calling unicodeToUtf8('بهروز') is to convert integers you got in array to hex & make sure they have 4digigts & prefix em with \u & you're done. also you can get same using json_encode

```
json_encode('بهروز') // returns "\u0628\u0647\u0631\u0648\u0632"
```

**EDIT:**

seems you want to get character codes of بب which first one differs from second one, all you have to do is applying bidi algorithm on your text using [fribidi_log2vis](http://ir.php.net/manual/en/function.fribidi-log2vis.php) then getting character code by one of ways i said before.

here's example:

```
$string = 'بب'; // \u0628\u0628
$bidiString = fribidi_log2vis($string, FRIBIDI_LTR, FRIBIDI_CHARSET_UTF8);
json_encode($bidiString); // \ufe90\ufe91
```

**EDIT:**

i just remembered that tcpdf has bidi algorithm which implemented using pure php so if you can not get fribidi extension of php to work, you can use tcpdf (utf8Bidi by default is protected so you need to make it public)

```
require_once('utf8.inc'); // http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/
require_once('tcpdf.php'); // http://www.tcpdf.org/
$t = new TCPDF();
$text = 'بب';
$t->utf8Bidi(utf8ToUnicode($text)); // will return an array like array(0 => 65168, 1 => 65169)
```

Comment: well, thank you for this answer, but I don't think utf8.inc will be available in any server + I don't know how to use it! json_encode give the same value to a character regardless it's position in the word. if you see the link up there, when you tick the Arabic ligatures box you got different volume for each - example  'ننن' is the same character but it's shown as 'uFEE7\uFEE8\uFEE6' how I suppose to know to get these + how to reconvert in to the Arabic again? you think unicodeToUtf8 will do the trick?

Comment: all you need to do is applying bidi algorithm before getting characters code, i've edited answer :)

Comment: I didn't success to install fribidi. utf8ToUnicode is a good function I think they need to add it into php 6

Answer (score 2):

Just set the element containing the arabic text to "rtl" (right to left), then input correctly spelled arabic and the text will flow with all ligatures looked for.

div {
direction:rtl;
}

On a side note, don't forget to read ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Think about that : The "ba" (ب) arabic letter is a "ba" no matter where it appears in the sentence.

Comment: nice contribution. I'm sorry that I didn't show you for what I want to do that. actually I want to use arabic words in flash using javascript swfobject, but unfortunately, the word shown in pieces and from ltr. I go over the second problem 'ltr' by using strrev fucntion but the word still as is in pieces even with the a class that specify the direction to rtl; I can't say this is not the right answer for my question, so if you know anything about this situation you can tell me :)

Comment: +1 for the link, Al3bed will be able to formulate the question a lot better with that info...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $string = 'a';
    $expanded = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-32', $string);
    $arr = unpack('L*', $expanded);
    print_r($arr);
?>
```

Comment: what is the best using iconv or mb_convert_encoding? and what is the encoding of Arabic language - assumption that I already have UTF-8 content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally agree with [FloatBird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781563/floatbird) about the use of the arabic.php which you will find it as he said at [ar-php](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ar-php/files/), The thing is they have changed the class name after version 4 from **Arabic** to **I18N_Arabic** so in order for the code to work using arabic.php ver 4.0 you need to change the code to

```
<?php
include('Arabic.php');
$Arabic = new I18N_Arabic('ArGlyphs');

$text = 'بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم';
$text = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs($text);
echo $text;
?>
```

Also notice that you need to put the php code file inside the **I18N** folder.

Anyway it is working fantastically, Thanks again [FloatBird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781563/floatbird)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to store an object that had values in Arabic, so writing in Arabic was stored as UNICODE," so the solution was as follows.

```
$detailsLog = $product->only(['name', 'unit', 'quantity']);
$detailsLog = json_encode($detailsLog, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$log->details = $detailsLog;
$log->save();
```

When you put the second parameter of the json_encode     **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE** follower, the Arabic words return without encoding.

Answer (score -1):

i think you could try:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

if this does not work use FloatBird Answer