# How to read arabic filenames in GD library?

Tags: php, thumbnails, arabic, gdlib

I'm facing a problem with Arabic filenames, for example when there is an image with Arabic file name, I'm not able to generate thumbnail from it but when the file in English everything is OK.

I tried many thumbs generators but all of them have this issue, after some search it's GD library problem.

I found a solution with copying the image to new destination after renaming it to some random English name but it's not an option because it will take some time and make web site very slow because of huge numbers of images.

So any idea how to solve it and generate thumbs with Arabic support?

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a copy you can probably create a symbolic link with [symlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) and read from that. No file copy required and you can remove the link when you're done.

```
<?php 
$filename = "somefile.jpg";
$linkname="linkedfile.jpg";
if (symlink($filename, $linkname)) {
    if (($im = imagecreatefromjpeg($linkname)) === false) {
        echo "couldn't create GD image";
    } else {
    echo "GD Image created successfully.";
    }

} else {
    echo ("Couldn't create symlink");
}
?>
```

**Note** that symbolic links aren't supported by Windows versions less than Vista or Server 2008, so this won't be an option.

Comment: Define 'not working'. I've added sample code that works on my Linux system. Do you see an error message?

Comment: This stackoverflow post I think will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175053/how-to-convert-arabic-characters-to-unicode-using-php