# PHP encoding utf-8

Tags: php, html, excel, encoding

I have a html file that want pars tags(Title,A,Name,...) and save them to a excel file .
html tags is persian and when save them into excel file not save corectly.
html file:

```
<html dir="rtl"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="fa">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>ÈÇäß ÕæÊ.ÂãæÒÔ.ÇÏÈíÇÊ.ÚæÇãá Ýí ÇáäÍæ.ÇÓÊÇÏ ãÏÑÓ ÇÝÛÇäí.ÌáÓå 1</title>
<meta name="generator" M.H.SAFARZADE TEHRANI   E_BANK_JAME_EMAMALI>
```

for example i want save title but not save corectly . title tag trust value is :

تدريس استاد مدرس افغاني

but save : ÈÇäß ÕæÊ.ÂãæÒÔ.ÇÏÈíÇÊ.ÚæÇãá Ýí ÇáäÍæ.ÇÓÊÇÏ ãÏÑÓ ÇÝÛÇäí.ÌáÓå 1

in php file i do this :

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and :

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($title, "UTF-8");
```

i can't find answer for my question in web.

please help me ...

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [php header excel and utf-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368150/php-header-excel-and-utf-8)

Comment: can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175053/how-to-convert-arabic-characters-to-unicode-using-php

Comment: 1) The encoding of the original appears to be Windows-1256 (according to the meta tag); you will have to do an explicit conversion from Windows-1256 to UTF-8 at some point. 2) How exactly are you passing the data to Excel? If you're producing an actual .xls(x) file with libraries which support just that, it should work. If you're just dumping CSV data, Excel notoriously sucks at importing CSV data correctly (or other plaintext formats for that matter). So in that case, confirm whether it looks okay using a good text editor first, instead of Excel.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)