# PHP: convert arabic word to unicode symbols

Tags: php, unicode

I want convert Arabic words to Unicode symbols

Sample:  `العربية` to `&#xFE94;&#xFEF4;&#xFE91;&#xFEAE;&#xFECC;&#xFEDF;&#xFE8D;`

I use `mb_convert_encoding` but not work

Comment: Those are htmlentities, not unicode symbols.

Comment: @tkausl `echo htmlentities("العربية");` return `العربية` not unicode

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6218155/6030450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// text: `العربية`

// expected: `&#xFE94;&#xFEF4;&#xFE91;&#xFEAE;&#xFECC;&#xFEDF;&#xFE8D;`

```
<?php

$originalText = 'العربية';
$convertedText = mb_convert_encoding($originalText, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'); 
$decodedText = html_entity_decode($convertedText);

echo 'Original Text: '. $originalText;
echo '<hr />';
echo 'Converted Text: '. $convertedText;
echo '<hr />';
echo 'Converted Text (display in html): '. htmlentities($convertedText);
echo '<hr />';
echo 'Decoded Text: '. $decodedText;
```

References:
 - [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)
 - [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.htmlentities.php)
 - [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Your code return `Original Text: العربيةConverted Text: العربيةDecoded Text: العربية` for me

Comment: Please check html source, other case you will see same result on html view.

Comment: Updated my answer, htmlentities($convertedText) will display it in html